# if condition to folder branch in Jenkinsfile

Tags: if-statement, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, git-branch

I have branch folder "feature-set" under this folder there's multibranch

I need to run the below script in my Jenkinsfile with a condition if this build runs from any branches under the "feature-set" folder like "feature-set/" then run the script

> the script is:

sh """

```
if [ ${env.BRANCH_NAME} = "feature-set*" ]
          then
                echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME}
                branchName='${env.BRANCH_NAME}' | cut -d'\\/' -f 2
                echo \$branchName
                npm install
                ng build --aot --output-hashing none --sourcemap=false                                                           
          fi
```

"""

the current output doesn't get the condition:

- [ feature-set/swat5 = feature-set* ]
  any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would re-write this to be primarily Jenkins/Groovy syntax and only go to shell when required.

Based on the info you provided I assume your env.BRANCH_NAME always looks like `feature-set/

```
// Echo first so we can see value if condition fails
echo(env.BRANCH_NAME)
// startsWith better than contains() based on current usecase
if ( (env.BRANCH_NAME).startsWith('feature-set') ) {
    // Split branch string into list based on delimiter
    List<String> parts = (env.BRANCH_NAME).tokenize('/')
    /**
     * Grab everything minus the first part 
     * This handles branches that include additional '/' characters 
     * e.g. 'feature-set/feat/my-feat'
     */
    branchName = parts[1..-1].join('/')
    echo(branchName)
    sh('npm install && ng build --aot --output-hashing none --sourcemap=false')
}
```

Comment: Noting here you can also use `(env.BRANCH_NAME).endsWith('feature-set')` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more on shell side. Since you are planning to use shell if condition the below worked for me.

Administrator1@XXXXXXXX:
$ if [[ ${BRANCH_NAME} = feature-set* ]]; then echo "Success"; fi
Success

Remove the quotes and add an additional "[]" at the start and end respectively.

The additional "[]" works as regex